# How to validate input and then check for correct answer in HTML Input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

1. **Validation**: I wish to validate by allowing only for two decimals at max from user, failing which I wish to remind by a validation message.
2. **Correctness**: On clicking submit, I wish to display a "Correct" or "Incorrect"
   message. The correctness of the input is checked by comparing with a "dcorrect" attribute, and the message is displayed.

In my current code, as I change input, the answer is checked for correctness even before pressing the Submit button. Secondly, there is no validation error when I key in multiple decimal places.

```js
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
         if (textbox.value == textbox.getAttribute("dcorrect"))  {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Correct Answer');
    }
    else  {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Incorrect Answer');
    }
    };
    
$(document).on('keydown', 'input[pattern]', function(e){
  var input = $(this);
  var oldVal = input.val();
  var regex = new RegExp(input.attr('pattern'), 'g');

  setTimeout(function(){
    var newVal = input.val();
    if(!regex.test(newVal)){
      input.val(oldVal); 
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input type="number" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" id="q4" dcorrect=14.23 placeholder="number">minutes
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native [client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), then you cannot use `setCustomValidity` with a **success** message because any non-empty string will cause the form to be in error and not submittable. Additionally, the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute can not be used when `type="number"`.

> The pattern attribute is an attribute of the text, tel, email, url, password, and search input types.

You can still use a custom error message, however:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('q4')

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  input.setCustomValidity('')

  if (!input.validity.valid) {
    input.setCustomValidity('Incorrect Answer')
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="q4" placeholder="number" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$">minutes
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to show a custom success message on submit, then use a `submit` handler and check that the form fields are valid before showing the message in the DOM:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('q4')
const form = document.getElementById('myform')
const success = document.getElementById('success')

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  input.setCustomValidity('')

  if (!input.validity.valid) {
    input.setCustomValidity('Incorrect Answer')
  }
})

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  success.classList.remove('show')
 
  if (input.validity.valid) {
    success.classList.add('show')
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="q4" placeholder="number" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$">minutes
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<p id="success">Success</p>
```

There's many different ways to do this, so you have to decide in what capacity you'd like to use the native client-side validation messages and which `input` type's you'd like to use (text/number/etc.).

Comment: Sorry I am confused - the correctness is obtained by checking against the "dcorrect" attribute in the question but this is missing in your answer?

Comment: @Bravo your description states `I wish to validate by allowing only for two decimals at max from user`. Either your description is wrong or the code you provided is wrong. If you only want to check that the provided number is exactly `14.23` then that would be a different question.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear - the title is "validate" and then "check for correctness". In my case, validation is checking if the input is a number with two decimal places, and correctness is a match with the dcorrect attribute.